# psexec over ssh not reading computer name properly

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am working on a Bash script to let me run GUI applications remotely on a Windows machine via psexec, but the psexec command doesn't seem to be reading the computer name right. It just errors out stating "The system cannot find the file specified. PsExec could not start 192.168.1.3:"

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh user@192.168.1.3 psexec \\192.168.1.3 -i 1 -s $1
```

ssh'ing in and running the psexec as a standalone command inside the remote shell functions just fine, but this doesn't.

It was working earlier with four backslashes (not sure what was changed), but now that just gives the error of "The system cannot find the file specified. PsExec could not start \192.168.1.3:" Adding more backslashes didn't help either.

Comment: Does `ssh user@192.168.1.3 "psexec \\192.168.1.3 -i 1 -s $1"` with quote marks behave any differently?

Comment: @SHawarden Nope, same result.

Comment: What does adding two more \s do? `ssh user@192.168.1.3 "psexec \\\\192.168.1.3 -i 1 -s $1"` or `ssh user@192.168.1.3 "psexec '\\192.168.1.3' -i 1 -s $1"`

Comment: @SHawarden Doing both did it.

So: ssh user@192.168.1.3 "psexec '\\\\192.168.1.3' -i 1 -s $1"

Comment: Produced the same error or worked as desired?

Comment: @SHawarden Worked as desired! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.3 "psexec \\\\192.168.1.3 -i 1 -s $1"
```

or

```
ssh user@192.168.1.3 "psexec '\\192.168.1.3' -i 1 -s $1"
```

The Single quoted contents are interpreted literally.